# UIImageView animation for large image sequence

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Using UIImageView I am trying to animate an image sequence of 300 PNG files, it works fine on the simulator however on actual device this doesn't work at all and what i see is a blank sereen.

If I am right then this is possibly due to the large number of images (300 approx.) that I am trying to load and animate or is there any other issue. Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how big the .png files are, which test device you're using etc. When you test on the simulator it has access to all the computers RAM, which is considerably more than an iPhone does. I'll try to improve my answer if you post up some code. It sounds like there is a better way to do it.

Have you tried using a small subsection of the frames (say 10) and see if that works? You could also profile your app and check whats going on that way?

Comment: Yeah, I agree; what have you tried already to debug the matter?